# Phasor Diagram of Voltage and Current

Tags: electromagnetism

The analysis of an a.c. circuit is facilitated by the use of phasor diagrams.

In an a.c. circuit, voltage and current are represented by phasors i.e. rotating vectors. Now, both voltage and current are scalar quantities and not vectors.

So,
 **why are these quantities represented as vectors in a.c. circuit? Is there no other optimum way to represent them?**

Comment: A phasor is _not_ a rotating vector, but a constant one. Please, see [this answer of mine](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/231659/87069) on EE.SE.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano My high-school book says that it is a rotating vector...

Comment: Your high-school book is unfortunately wrong: I suggest you to refer to a good book on circuit theory. You can also have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor), you will see that the phasor is not a rotating vector.

Comment: @Sid A phasor is a harmonically varying scalar represented by rotating vectors. The term phasor generally refers to a static vector, $Ae^{i\theta}$

Answer (score -1):

These quantities together make up a vector, and are not vectors themselves. Just as x- and y- coordinates are scalars, but a displacement ($\mathbf{d}$) is a vector.

$$ \mathbf{d} = \left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y \end{array}\right) $$

Phasors are very handy because you can represent them using Euler's identity $$e^{i \omega t} = \cos(\omega t) + i \sin(\omega t)$$. So if a phasor has a amplitude A, angular frequency $\omega$, and a phase $\phi$ at $t=0$, it's phase at any future point is described completely by

$$ A(t) = Ae^{i\omega t + \phi}$$

A phasor merely 'packages' these values into the real and complex parts of A(t).

$$ \mathbf{A} = \left(\begin{array}{c} v \\ i \end{array}\right) $$

Or $$A = v + ji, \text{where } j \equiv \sqrt{-1} $$

Complex numbers have a lot of useful properties that make phasor analysis elegant and at-times easy. Whether or not it is "optimum" likely depends on your application, but in m$ost applications I personally have encountered, phasors yield the most elegant and fastest solutions.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your first statement? I don't understand, what vector do they make?

Comment: Hope that helps.

Comment: This is not a very clear answer.